# Iterate through a Map by key

Tags: java

I got the following error by trying to iterate through a HashMap by a key value:

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

I found some answers but those use `.entrySet()` and I need to iterate using a key value. This is my code so far:

```
for (ProtocolNode pendingNode : this.getPendingNodes().get(ExtractNumber(jid))){
  // Do stuff (ExractNumber is a String)
}
```

And the function:

```
public HashMap<String, ProtocolNode> getPendingNodes()
{
   return this.pending_nodes;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you've got 1 key value only, then there is no need for iterating... Please elaborate and give more details on your issue.

Comment: may i know what type are you using for <key,value> ?

Comment: Could you describe your problem a bit more? Do you want to loop over a single key or all keys? For the first one, if your value doesn´t represent something you can iterate over, then you´ll have the specific value you want yet, otherwise just use `this.getPendingNodes().entrySet()`.

Comment: @StefanBeike, it will return ProtocolNode

Comment: @KevinEsche I want to iterate through the full HashMap and only return the matches as ProtocolNode pendingNode

Comment: @JohnDoe if you want to iterate over a `Map` to get matches then you are in some way using the map the wrong way. Your key value should notify you about matches and you shouldn´t be in need to iterate over the map again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to iterate over a map you need to keep a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) instance.
Therefore change your map as below:

```
public HashMap<String, List<ProtocolNode>> getPendingNodes()
{
   return this.pending_nodes;
}
```

or to fix your own code use below method:

```
Map<String, ProtocolNode> testMap = new HashMap<String, ProtocolNode>();

        for( Entry<String, ProtocolNode> entry : testMap.entrySet() ){
            if( entry.getKey().equals( "MYKEY" ) ){
                System.out.println( entry.getValue() );
            }
        }
```

You have to use entryset, there's no other way.

Comment: using `testMap.containsKey()` as a condition would be a lot more performant instead of looping over the whole `Map`.

Comment: If he wants to reach the value he must use entryset, otherwise you are correct @KevinEsche.

Comment: If it helps, please accept as an answer for further reference @JohnDoe

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I know, I had to wait before I could accept

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the method get in the javadoc.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

You will see that it returns a value, you can't iterate over a value.
You are just accessing one item, the item associated with the 'jid'.

If you take a look at this answer: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap) you can see how to iterate over a hashmap. And you will just need to use 'getPendingNodes()' to get the HashMap.

Comment: this is only partionally true, If the `Map` would be defined as `Map<String,List<String>>` then you could use the get method to iterate over the list value.

Comment: @JohnDoe take a look at the link. 
and Kevin: yeah that is true :-)