# Count the occurence of word in a list containing sentences

Tags: java, list

I am having some problem with Java programming which includes List. Basically, what I am trying to count the occurences of each word in a sentence from a list containing several sentences. 
The code for the list containing sentences is as below:

```
List<List<String>> sort = new ArrayList<>();
for (String sentence : complete.split("[.?!]\\s*"))
{
    sort.add(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("[ ,;:]+"))); //put each sentences in list
}
```

The output from the list is as follows:

```
[hurricane, gilbert, head, dominican, coast]
[hurricane, gilbert, sweep, dominican, republic, sunday, civil, defense, alert, heavily, populate, south, coast, prepare, high, wind]
[storm, approach, southeast, sustain, wind, mph, mph]
[there, alarm, civil, defense, director, a, television, alert, shortly]
```

The **output desired** should be as follows (only an example). It will output all the unique word in the list and calculate the occurences by sentences.

```
Word: hurricane
Sentence 1: 1 times
Sentence 2: 1 times
Sentence 3: 0 times
Sentence 4: 0 times

Word: gilbert
Sentence 1: 0 times
Sentence 2: 2 times
Sentence 3: 1 times
Sentence 4: 0 times 

Word: head
Sentence 1: 3 times
Sentence 2: 2 times
Sentence 3: 0 times
Sentence 4: 0 times 

and goes on....
```

With the example above, the word 'hurricane' occur 1 time in the first sentence, 1 time in second sentence, none in third sentence and none in forth sentence. 
How do I achieve the output? I was thinking of a 2D matrices for building them. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: could you include what the input is right now?

Comment: Hi, I've already included the output as above. The one from the list. It looks weird because I've removed the stop word (exp: the, a , an) and stem the words (exp: knew -> know)

Comment: Is the count correct? because gilbert only appear once in sentence 1 and once in sentence 2. But in your output it says different.

Comment: Opps. the count is not accurate. That's just an example but I've edited it(only for hurricane)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution. I did not take care of the printing. The result is a Map -> Word, Array. Where Array contains the count of Word in each sentence indexed from 0. Runs in O(N) time. Play here: https://repl.it/Bg6D

```
    List<List<String>> sort = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> res = new HashMap<>();

    // split by sentence
    for (String sentence : someText.split("[.?!]\\s*")) {
        sort.add(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("[ ,;:]+"))); //put each sentences in list
    }

    // put all word in a hashmap with 0 count initialized
    final int sentenceCount = sort.size();
    sort.stream().forEach(sentence -> sentence.stream().forEach(s -> res.put(s, new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(sentenceCount, 0)))));

    int index = 0;
    // count the occurrences of each word for each sentence.
    for (List<String> sentence: sort) {
        for (String s : sentence) {
            res.get(s).set(index, res.get(s).get(index) + 1);
        }
        index++;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
In answer to your comment.

```
  List<Integer> getSentence(int sentence, Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map) {
     return map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getValue().get(sentence)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Then you can call

```
List<Integer> sentence0List = getSentence(0, res);
```

However be aware that this approach is not optimal since it runs in O(K) time with K being the number of sentences. For small K it is totally fine but it does not scale. You have to clarify yourself what will you do with the result. If you need to call `getSentence` many times, this is not the correct approach. In that case you will need the data structured differently. Something like

```
Sentences = [
         {'word1': N, 'word2': N},... // sentence 1 
         {'word1': N, 'word2': N},... // sentence 2
```

]

So you are able to easily access the word count per each sentence.

**EDIT 2:**
Call this method:

```
  Map<String, Float> getFrequency(Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> stringMap) {
    Map<String, Float> res = new HashMap<>();
    stringMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> res.put(e.getKey()
                , e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() / (float)e.getValue().size()));
    return res;
  }
```

Will return something like this:

```
{standard=0.25, but=0.25, industry's=0.25, been=0.25, 1500s=0.25, software=0.25, release=0.25, type=0.5, when=0.25, dummy=0.5, Aldus=0.25, only=0.25, passages=0.25, text=0.5, has=0.5, 1960s=0.25, Ipsum=1.0, five=0.25, publishing=0.25, took=0.25, centuries=0.25, including=0.25, in=0.25, like=0.25, containing=0.25, printer=0.25, is=0.25, t
```

Comment: thx for ur time. Your solution works but is there a way I could access all the first value from each word? For example,  {to=[0, 1, 0, 0], popularised=[0, 0, 0, 1], simply=[1, 0, 0, 0]} -> I'll get 0,0,1 (value from first data of each word).

Comment: It is easily possible, however it depends on what you actually need. Do you need grouping per word or per sentence? I made the solution considering that you needed a per word segmentation. Anyway I make a small edit to get the sentence count

Comment: Thanks. Btw one last thing, I need to get the total occurences for each word, sum them up, and divide by the total number of sentences. Something like this for each word: Exp 1: prepare=[0, 1, 0, 0] -> so 1/4. Exp 2: look=[1,1,0,0] -> so 2/4. These value may be stored somewhere. Appreciate ur help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem by first creating an index for each word. You could use a Hashmap and put just put all the single words on it, which you find in your text (so you would have no need for checking double occurrences).

Then you can [iterate the HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap) and check for every Word in every sentence. You can count occurrences by using the [indexOf method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) of your list. As long as it returns a value greater than -1 you can count up the occurrence in the sentence. This method does only return the first occurrence so you

Some Pseudocode would be like:

Array sentences = text.split(sentence delimiter)

```
for each word in text
    put word on hashmap

for each entry in hashmap
   for each sentence
       int count = 0
       while subList(count, sentence.length) indexOf(entry) > -1
          count for entry ++
```

**Note** that this is very greedy and not performance oriented at all. Oh yea, and also note, that there are some [java nlp libraries](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20nlp%20library) out there which may have already solved your problem in a performance oriented and reusable way.

Answer (score 0):

First you can segment your sentences and then tokenize them using a text segmentor such as NLTK or Stanford tokenizer. Splitting the string (containing sentences) around "[.?!]" is not a good idea. What happens to an "etc." or "e.g." that occurs in the middle of the sentence? Splitting a sentence around "[ ,;:]" is also not a good idea. You can have plenty of other symbols in a sentence such as quotation marks, dash and so on.

After segmentation and tokenization you can split your sentences around space and store them in a `List<List<String>>`:

```
List<List<String>> sentenceList = new ArraList();
```

Then for your index you can create a `HashMap<String,List<Integer>>`:

```
HashMap<String,List<Integer>> words = new HashMap();
```

Keys are all words in all sentences. Values you can update as follows:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sentenceList.size() ; i++){
    for(String w : words){
        if(sentence.contains(w)){
           List tmp = words.get(w);
           tmp.get(i)++; 
           words.put(w, tmp);
         }
    }
}
```

This solution has the time complexity of O(number_of_sentences*number_of_words) which is equivalent to O(n^2). An optimized solution is:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < sentenceList.size() ; i++){
    for(String w : sentenceList.get(i)){
        List tmp = words.get(w);
        tmp.get(i)++; 
        words.put(w, tmp);
    }
}
```

This has the time complexity of O(number_of_sentences*average_length_of_sentences). Since average_length_of_sentences is usually small this is equivalent to O(n).