# Iterator concurrentmodificationerror (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop, iterator, set, maps

My code (cut down to bare essentials is below); it's throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` when the `hasNext()` is called the last time-
PS- I've tried debugging it and I cannot seem to determine how to make it work. If I switch the remove and add methods, it works, but it removes the only value if somethingElse = something which isn't really helpful.

PS- I know of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap); but I need it to add AFTER removing the value which is causing the problem

```
Iterator<String> itr = something.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    String x = itr.next();
    itr.remove();
    somethingElse.add(x);            
}
```

Edit- somethingElse can be something or a new object all-together (there's a loop that determines this)
This is my first post- if it's too abstract or if the code isn't clear, let me know and I'll post my full code.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you sure `something` and `somethingElse` are two unrelated objects?

Comment: can you clarify what is `somethingElse`. Every operation that happens in loop must be through iterator. If iteration is not used that throws the `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: somethingElse can be something (there's a loop that determines whether somethingElse is something or a new object)

Comment: You cannot add to the collection while using an iterator on it... I would suggest adding to a new object and then copying after the iteration is complete...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll try it out and get back, albeit it is odd that it works initially (when somethingElse is a new object and something) until the last value is left to process. After it processes the last value and checks for hasNext(), it spits out the error. I'll create a map and do this and post back if it works though, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is understood by your question- any point of time `SomethingElse` can be `something`.

If that's the case you will get `concurrentModificationException` as you are iterating over the list and at the same time you are updating it.

So `iterator` has no clue what is going on in the underlying `data structure` it will stick to it's policy of `fail-fast` before something goes horribly wrong.

(Core value followed by `JDK` : *Read and write should be handled gracefully*)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for explaining that. However, swapping the order of removing and adding fixes the error; can you kindly explain me why that is before I mark the question solved?

Comment: Swapping order doesn't make any difference. Might be when you ran after swapping that `someThingElse` was really a new list which satisfied `JVM` and it worked for you but in all other cases it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.remove` is throwing that error because you are modifying the list while iterating thorugh it. You can use ConcurrentHashMap and CopyOnWriteArrayList classes to fix this error.

Refer to the link [here](http://www.journaldev.com/378/how-to-avoid-concurrentmodificationexception-when-using-an-iterator) for clear cut explanation about the error.