# Merge data by date

Tags: java

I have below data which I fetched from database by using `Hibernate NamedQuery`

```
  TXN_ID   END_DATE 
---------- ------------
       121 15-JUN-16
       122 15-JUN-16
       123 16-MAY-16
```

Each row data can be store in Java class Object. 
Now I want to combined data depending on the END_DATE. If END_DATE are same then merge TXN_ID data.

From the above data output would be :

```
TXN_ID     END_DATE 
---------- ------------
121|122    15-JUN-16
123        16-MAY-16
```

I want to do this program in java. What is the easy program for that?

Comment: what you had tried so far ..??

Answer (score 0):

Using the accepted function [printMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap), to iterate through the hashmap in order to see if output is correct.

With the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] b = {{"1","15-JUN-16"},{"2","16-JUN-16"},{"3","13-JUN-16"},{"4","16-JUN-16"},{"5","17-JUN-16"}};
    Map<String, String> mapb = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++){
        String c = mapb.get(b[j][1]);
        if(c == null)
            mapb.put(b[j][1], b[j][0]);
        else
            mapb.put(b[j][1], c+" "+b[j][0]);
    }
    printMap(mapb);
}
```

You get the following output:

```
13-JUN-16 = 3
16-JUN-16 = 2 4
17-JUN-16 = 5
15-JUN-16 = 1
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With hibernate you can put query result in a list of object

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery( sql ).addEntity(ObjDataQuery.class);
List<ObjDataQuery> res = q.list();
```

Now you can create an hashmap to storage final result, to populate this object you can iterate over `res`

```
Map<String, String> finalResult= new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++){
    if (finalResult.get(res.get(i).date!=null){
       //new element
       finalResult.put(res.get(i).date,res.get(i).txn)
    } else {
       //update element
       finalResult.put(res.get(i).date,
                       finalResult.get(res.get(i).date) + res.get(i).txn)
    }
}
```

I've not tested it by logic should be correct.

Another way is to change the query to obtain direct the final result (in oracle see LISTAGG)