# How to get Hashmap Data

Tags: android, hashmap, android-recyclerview

I had seen many examples regarding Hashmap Data but I am not getting the data as required.

Here is my code:

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> citylist = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> Gujarat = new ArrayList<String>();
    Gujarat.add("Surat");
    Gujarat.add("Baroda");
    Gujarat.add("Ahmedabad");

    ArrayList<String> Rajasthan = new ArrayList<String>();
    Rajasthan.add("Udaipur");
    Rajasthan.add("Jaipur");

    ArrayList<String> UP= new ArrayList<String>();
    UP.add("Lucknow");
    UP.add("Agra");

    citylist.put("Gujarat", Gujarat);
    citylist.put("UP", UP);
    citylist.put("Rajasthan", Rajasthan);
```

It is in recyclerview how to get this type of data in BindViewHolder?
Toast is coming like:

```
   {Rajasthan=[Udaipur, Jaipur], UP=[Lucknow, Agra], Gujarat=[Surat, Baroda, Ahmedabad]}
```

I had used this method to get but error is coming:

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ArrayList<String> lst = citylist.get("" + position);
    for (Integer i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        holder.tv.setText(citylist.toString());
        Log.e("Hashmap....", ""+holder.tv );
    }
```

the output should be like Gujarat is state and surat baroda and ahmedabad are cities?

Comment: are these static or dynamic

Comment: Dynamic..@Chirag Arora

Comment: try my code which i have posted

Comment: I am Still not getting: 'citylist.get("" + position);' here "" is the key for three.

Comment: Give me link @VishalThakkar

Comment: see below. dear i have posted code.

Comment: @Abhi ok check my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through a HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create one `ArrayList` with all state :

```
ArrayList<String> stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
stateList.add("Gujarat");
stateList.add("UP");
stateList.add("Rajasthan");
```

Second create one `HashMap` with each state name as `Key` and each state city as `Value`:

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> stateCityMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>()

ArrayList<String> gujaratCityList = new ArrayList<String>();
gujaratCityList.add("Ahmedabad");
gujaratCityList.add("Surat");
gujaratCityList.add("Baroda");
.......................

ArrayList<String> upCityList = new ArrayList<String>();
upCityList.add("Lucknow");
upCityList.add("Agra");
..........................

ArrayList<String> rajasthanCityList = new ArrayList<String>();
rajasthanCityList.add("Udaipur");
rajasthanCityList.add("Jaipur");
...........................

stateCityMap.put("Gujarat",gujaratCityList);
stateCityMap.put("UP",upCityList);
stateCityMap.put("Rajasthan",rajasthanCityList);
```

Now get all city name based on state in `Adapter` :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
   Log.e("State : ",stateList.get(position));
   ArrayList<String> cityList=   (ArrayList<String>)stateCityMap.get(stateList.get(position));
   for(String cityName : cityList){
      Log.e("City : ",cityName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do I pass stateList in Custom Adapter?

Comment: @Abhi,Yes brother you have to pass both stateList as well stateCityMap into Adapter.

Comment: thank you I gotta solution from You and its the best one thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can get like below.

```
Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key=(String)iterator.next();
    String value=(String)map.get(key);
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Key: "+key+" Value: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMaps do not preserve ordering:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Take a look at [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which guarantees a predictable iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try something like this.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : citylist.entrySet()) 
{
    String key = entry.getKey();        // Your State
    String value = entry.getValue();    // Your List of Cities.

    // Split data and insert in Views
}
```

However I recommend (for easy to use case) keep a `List` of all the states and get `Value` from `HashMap` using keys from this `List` of states.

Comment: brada i got your answer but it showing me last one ie Gujarat Gujarat Gujarat.How can I get all Possible value?

Comment: Are you getting last key over and over? Are you using key inside or outside the loop?

Comment: The code is fine there seems to be some trouble implementing it from your end, check again and if still don't see any difference then update your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it :

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    h1.put("h1_key_1", "h1_value_1");
    h1.put("h1_key_2", "h1_value_2");
    arrayList.add(h1);

    for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : arrayList) {
    System.out.println(hashMap.keySet());
    for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(hashMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try This:

    public static void printMap(Map mp) {
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
}
```