# Delete entry from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap:

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> adjMap = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
adjMap.put(title, new HashSet<String>());
adjMap.get(title).add(cutTitle(graphLink));
```

Now I want do delete all entries from the values (HashSet), which does not contains as a key.

Here is my code so far:

```
for(String s: adjMap.keySet()){
    for(Set<String> s1: adjMap.values()){
        for(String s2: s1){
            if(!s.contains(s2)){
                s1.remove(s2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: You are trying to modify the Hashset in Foreach loop apart from it's using it's own iterator.

Comment: Use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`

Answer (score 2):

Iterate  your Map

```
Iterator it = adjMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
       Entry item = it.next();
       map.remove(item.getKey());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for-each loops are not allowed to alter the iterated object. To remove entries you should use an iterator.

Compare to [map-Iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap?rq=1) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead, or create a copy of your `HashMap` and make any changes to the copy.