# Remove unwanted information in gson JsonObject

Tags: android, parsing, gson, retrofit

I have a `JSONObject` response like

```
{
    "0:"{
        "name": "name1",
        "surname": "surname1",
        "id": "22",
        "motivations": []
    },
    "1:"{
        "name": "name2",
        "surname": "surname2",
        "id": "23",
        "motivations": []
    },
    "2:"{
        "name": "name3",
        "surname": "surname3",
        "id": "24",
        "motivations": []
    },
    "sign": "9e46b7d6b140b",
    "last_call": 1446
}
```

I want to map it to the `List<Person>` , but I cant do it before I erased 
`"0:","1:","2:" ,"sign":"9e46b7d6b140b","last_call":1446`.

Any idea how to map that in the model?

Comment: Change your API I guess.

Comment: The JSON form t is completely bad. For you to be able to use GSON it has to contain array of Person objects

Comment: so its the api fault? or I need to decode it diffrent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Person` class

```
class Person{
        String name;
        String surname;
        String id;
        String[] motivations;
         //Create getter setter for it
    }
```

Create `HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();`

```
map = new Gson().fromJson(responseData, HashMap.class);
```

And last Iterate over map

```
Iterator entries = map .entrySet().iterator();

while (entries.hasNext()) {
   String value = (String )entries.next().getValue();
 Object p;
 try{ 
    p = new Gson().fromJson(value , Person .class);
    \\person class
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    // catch exception
    p =null;
  }
  if(p!= null && p instanceOf Person)
  {
     \\create list and add it to the separate list 
    \\ entries.next().getKey()
    \\ entries.next().getValue()
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot implement entries.next().getValue(); (cannot resolve)


            HashMap <String,Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), HashMap.class);
                Iterator entries = map .entrySet().iterator();
                while (entries.hasNext()) {
                    String value = (String )entries.next().getValue();
                    Log.i(TAG,"cos ma "+value);
                    entries.next();

                }

Comment: @Expiredmind,Check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap I think that will help you