# No setter/field for found Android Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

I used FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to get all the childs of "Pro" using a Model class named " Spacecraft" and now I want to retrieve all the candidates into a child of Pro like "1"

I created a public static "candidat" into "Spacecraft" and I used the setters and getters but still the same error

This is my database:

[image: Database]

this is the Model Class

```
public class Spacecraft{
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private String last;
    private candidat candidat;

    public Spacecraft.candidat getCandidat() {
        return candidat;
    }

    public void setCandidat(Spacecraft.candidat candidat) {
        this.candidat = candidat;
    }

    public Spacecraft() {
    }
    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getLast() {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast(String last) {
        this.last = last;
    }
    public static class candidat{

        private String info;
        private String namecandid;
        public candidat(){}
        public String getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public void setInfo(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

        public String getNamecandid() {
            return namecandid;
        }

        public void setNamecandid(String namecandid) {
            this.namecandid = namecandid;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Spacecraft, candidatviewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter  = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Spacecraft, candidatviewholder>(
                Spacecraft.class,
                R.layout.candidat,
                candidatviewholder.class,
                query){
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(candidatviewholder viewHolder, Spacecraft model, int position) {
                            viewHolder.setName1(model.getCandidat().getNamecandid());
                            viewHolder.setInfo1(model.getCandidat().getInfo());
                        }
                    };
        rv.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

The error:

> No setter/field for key1 found on class com.example.ilyas.evotingapplication.Spacecraft$candidat

Comment: static class cant have constructor

Comment: i delete the constructor but still the same error :/ @uguboz

Comment: dont delete constructor. remove static from candidat class. and in Spacecraft set candidat by calling new candidat().

Comment: didn't work bro :/

Comment: Hi @ilyasshabi, try to move the `candidat` class from the inner class of `Spacecraft` to an independent class just like `Spacecraft`, also remove the static property.

Comment: HI @Wilik i tried but still not working

Answer (score 4):

I had this error but the above solutions didn't fix it. Hopefully, this alternate solution will help others. If you have that error occur for almost every variable, chances are that you have Proguard enabled and it is removing the un-used getter and setter methods. To fix this, add a line similar to this to your proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keep class com.example.yourapp.ObjectClass
```

where ObjectClass is the name of your java object class that is stored to Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just that your data models on Firebase and in Java differ.

In your java class, the `Spacecraft` class has a `candidat` field of type `Candidat`. But, in the database, the `candidat` field is really a nested object (map), containing one key `Key1`, which value is a `Candidat` structure.

So, depending on what did you want to achieve:

- if you wanted each spacecraft to have exactly one candidat: save the database object properly, so `{info: "info 1", namecandid: "name 1"}` is saved *directly* under `candidat` field, not one level deeper, so the field has type `Candidat` in the code.
- if you wanted each spacecraft to have a few candidats: instead of `private Candidat candidat` field, it should be typed `Map<String, Candidat>`, because that's the type it has in your database screenshot.

Comment: Hey quezak, thank u for ansewring  ! it's the second case; i want each spacecrft to have few candidats and populate them into a FirebaseRecycler;
i added this to Spacecraft " private Map<String, candidat> candidat; " (with getters, setters)
Can u tell me how can i retrieve data of this Map ?

Comment: @ilyasshabi iterate over it like a normal Java map :) see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1066607/1815209) for a simple explanation.

Comment: i'll iterate it into this function  populateViewHolder ?

Comment: @ilyasshabi I didn't use recycler adapters myself, so just the general idea -- if your query returns the whole spacecraft then inside iterate over the candidats map, or make a query that just returns all the candidats of one ship, then you don't have to deal with iteration inside.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:
-**keepclassmembers** class com.myPackageName.MyClassName { *; }