# Xamarin.Android iterate Java.Util.HashMap

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Anyone know the best way to iterate a Java HashMap in Xamarin.Android? According to [the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.Util.HashMap.EntrySet()/) it appears doing a foreach on EntrySet is suppose to return an instance of [IMapEntry](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Util.IMapEntry/) on each iteration, but I get an invalid cast when doing:

```
foreach(Java.Util.IMapEntry entry in hashMap.EntrySet())
```

Or if you'd rather tell me how to convert the HashMap to a .Net dictionary that would be find too as it is my end goal.

Note: this is for Xamarin.Android specifically and it doesn't seem to be as straight forward as the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

Comment: @JonDouglas I definitely looked at that, but was unable to translate it to C#/Xamarin

Comment: if you can't cast it to IMapEntry, what type does the debugger say that it actually is?

Comment: @Jason Java.Util.HashMap.HashMapEntry, which I am unable to figure out how to cast to. I have made some progress using JavaCast<JavaDictionary>, but still working through it. I'll of course post an answer if/when I come up with something complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashMap.EntrySet()` returns an `ICollection` and items of that collection that can not be cast to an `IMapEntry`.... issue? probably, but the root issue is trying to use Java generics in C# and thus a non-generic `EntrySet()` should return a list of HashMap.SimpleEntry (or SimpleImmutableEntry) but is not mapped that way in `Xamarin.Android`...

I work around this by using the the `Xamarin.Android` runtime JavaDictionary (`Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary`) as you can "cast" a `Hashmap` to its generic version and act upon it as a *normal* C# generic class.

Assuming you are creating or receiving a simple `HashMap` key/value (lots of the Google Android APIs use simple HashMaps to convert to Json for their Rest APIs, i.e. the Google Android Drive API makes use of a lot of HashMaps)

#### Create a Java HashMap (this is from a POCO or POJO):

```
var map = new HashMap();
map.Put(nameof(uuid), uuid);
map.Put(nameof(name), name);
map.Put(nameof(size), size);
```

#### Create a `JavaDictionary` from the `Handle` of a `Hashmap`:

```
var jdictionaryFromHashMap = new Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary<string, string>(map.Handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership.DoNotRegister);
```

#### Iterate the `JavaDictionary`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in jdictionaryFromHashMap)
{
    Log.Debug("SO", $"{item.Key}:{item.Value}");
}
```

#### Use Linq to create your C# Dictionary:

```
var dictionary = jdictionaryFromHashMap.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```