# HashMap - Getting "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

How do I search for a Hashmap that contains String as a key and list of objects as value?

```
HashMap<String,List<PageObjectBaseClass>> ObjList1;
```

When I used

```
for (HashMap<String,List<PageObjectBaseClass>> map : ObjList1)
```

Am getting the error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over the elements in ObjList1 or get a specific List out of ObjList1?

Comment: *FYI:* Java naming convention is for variables to start with lowercase letter, so variable should be named `objList1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. The one I find most idiomatic and expressive is [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
yourMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
    // key is of type String
    // value is List<PageObjectBaseClass>
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enumerate over the [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet--) like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<PageObjectBaseClass>> map : ObjList1.entrySet()){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the extended for-loop over objects that implement the `Iterable` interface. `Map` does not.

However it provides some utility method to access collections of its entries, keys and values which are of type `Iterable`. Therefore consider the following examples:

```
HashMap<A, B> map = new HashMap<>();

// Entries
for (Map.Entry<A, B> entry : map.entrySet​()) { ... }

// Keys
for (A key : map.keySet()) { ... }

// Values
for (B value : map.values()) { ... }
```

Here are links to the documentation of all three methods:

- Map#entrySet - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--)
- Map#keySet - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--)
- Map#values - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--)

Note that all three accesses are fast, `O(1)`. As you get collections that are internally used by the map. That is also why they are **backed by the map**, which means if you change something on the collections or the entries, the changes will be reflected inside the map too.

Answer (score 0):

This an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

```
public static void printMap(Map mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is very inferior to answer using `foreach`. First it uses `while` that unless you are on ancient Java, is not recommended any more. Second it uses raw type and cast which again is bad. Third it does `remove` entry from `Map` that OP did not ask for. And finally there is no reason to copy answer from another question. You can simply mark the question as duplicate.