# Removing items from a cache after a set period?

Tags: java, caching, hashmap, iterator

I am trying to create a cache that holds a messageID and a responsePayload (both bytes[]), and ensuring that each item in the cache expires after 5 seconds. Here is what I am currently trying to do.

I have the following class:

```
public class CacheObject {
    public byte[] responsePayload;
    public long time;

    public CacheObject(byte[] responsePayload) {
        this.responsePayload = responsePayload;
        this.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Using this class I have created the following cache with messageID as the key and CacheObject as the value

```
private static HashMap<byte[], CacheObject> cache = new HashMap<byte[], CacheObject>();
```

Then I call a function everytime I loop through the main part of my program:

```
private static void updateCache() {
    Collection times = cache.values();
    Iterator itr = times.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        CacheObject cacheObject = itr.next();
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - cacheObject.time > 5000) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

However the problem I am facing is I cannot seem to assign the iterator object to my CacheObject in this line:

```
CacheObject cacheObject = itr.next();
```

I've seen a few posts where this is suggested, but it does not seem to work for me. Is there a way around this issue, or is there a better way to implement this cache removal?

Comment: Why not iterator entrySet and remove? [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use raw types! You are getting that error because your iterator is not correctly typed. Declare it as:

```
Collection<CacheObject> times = cache.values();
Iterator<CacheObject> itr = times.iterator();
```

---

**Edit:**

There's a much better way to implement your `updateCache` method:

```
private static void updateCache() {
    cache.values().removeIf(c -> System.currentTimeMillis() - c.time > 5000);
}
```

Where `c` is of type `CacheObject`, matching the type of the values of your map.

Check [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method docs for further reference.

Comment: or even better, use guava that has a policy for this

Comment: Hi @Eugene. That's true. But I didn't want to introduce it here, I just wanted to stick to the specific context of the question. Anyways, Guava's cache is great