# Iterate through a hashmap with an arraylist?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

So I have a basic hashmap with an arraylist:

```
Map<Text, ArrayList<Text>> map = new HashMap<Text, ArrayList<Text>>();
```

Say I have a key value pair: Key: Apple, Value: orange, red, blue

I already understand how to iterate through to print the key and it’s values like so:
Apple, orange, red, blue

but is there a way to break up the values/iterate through the inner ArrayList and print the key/value pair three separate times/print the key with each value separately like:

```
Apple orange
Apple red
Apple blue
```

Comment: That shouldn't be difficult, put your solution and we will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

Answer (score 3):

You could use a nested loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<Text, ArrayList<Text>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (Text text : entry.value()) {
        System.out.println(entry.key() + " " + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this still just show the complete list of values per key?

Comment: @JaneDow no, each row will have the key and one value from the array list.

Answer (score 3):

Using simple `for` loops, this would be:

```
for (Map.Entry<Text, ArrayList<Text>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for (Text text : entry.value()) {
        System.out.println(entry.key() + " " + text);
    }
}
```

Doing the same in a functional way:

```
map.forEach((key, valueList) ->
    valueList.forEach(listItem -> System.out.println(key + " " + listItem)
));
```