# I want to loop through hashmap and call the method of object in it

Tags: java

I have a hashmap with 2 objects, Parcel and Deliverer. Both have a getName function. I want to loop the hashmap and print there names like (Parcel.getName(), Deliverer.getName()).

```
for (Map.Entry<Parcel, Deliverer> entry : deliveryList.entrySet()) {
                for (Parcel key: entry) {
                    System.out.println("Package : " + key.getName());
                    for (Deliverer deliverer: entry) {
                        System.out.println("- Deliverer : " + deliverer.getName());
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: See if this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way can be using passing BiConsumer to forEach directly

```
deliveryList.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Package: " + key.getName() + "- Deliver: " + value.getName()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Not any different from @funkyjelly. An upvote :)

Same thing, just with Java8 collection foreach syntax.

```
deliveryList.entrySet().forEach( entry -> 
           System.out.println("Package : " + entry.getKey().getName());
           System.out.println("Deliverer: " + entry.getValue().getName());
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the map entries you'd only need to invoke `getKey()` to get Parcel and `getValue()` to get Deliverer for each entry. 
Hence it should be like this :

```
for (Map.Entry<Parcel, Deliverer> entry : deliveryList.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Package : " + entry.getKey().getName() + 
          "- Deliverer : " + entry.getValue().getName());
}
```